# UIImageView getting resized when using presentViewController on top

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview

My main viewController has 4 UIImageViews that take up the whole screen. Each one contains an image and is set to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit. Each autoresizingMask is set to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight.

I have several modal screens that get presented via the main viewController's [self presentViewController:_modal animated:YES completion:nil];

And this is where it gets crazy.

This works perfectly for several of the modal screens...but not with 2 others. When I present either of these offending modal viewControllers, the UIImageViews below change frame size to the actual size of the image they contain...and I have no idea why. This happens on iPhone and iPad.

What would cause a UIImageView to change it's frame/bounds by itself?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that even though I'm not using constraints, just putting this line:

```
_imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

in my setup code forces the subviews to be resized when using SOME modal view controllers.

Yeah, I'm confused too.

I hope that helps somebody out there.

Comment: iOS 6 is always using constraints under the hood (I think). Turning off auto layout in your storyboard or xib doesn’t change this, so disabling autoresizing mask translation on a per-view basis still switches it to use Auto Layout.